# Gradle/Gcc C++ compilation and JNI; having java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: undefined symbol: _ZN4RF24C1Ettj at run

Tags: java, c++, gradle, java-native-interface

I built a library with Java wrapper to receive message from an RF24 component.
I have no compilation issues but when I run my applicaion and that I want to load my native library with `System.loadLibrary`, I have the error :

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /usr/lib/libtransmitter.so: /usr/lib/libtransmitter.so: undefined symbol: _ZN4RF24C1Ettj
```

I double checked that I included the necessary headers for RF24.
I double checked that **libtransmitter.so** is copied in **/usr/lib/** .
I just can't understand why I have this issue.

[The source code here](https://gitlab.com/kowlown/raspberry-rf24)

Comment: The missing symbol is `RF24::RF24(unsigned short, unsigned short, unsigned int)`, which should come from librf24.so. Does `nm` show that that symbol is present in librf24.so? And does `ldd` show that libtransmitter depends on librf24?

Comment: You're right. ldd show me that libtransmitter does not have librf24 as its dependency 
Seems an issue with the linking with gradle

Comment: To answer your first question the symbol is present in librf24.so

Comment: Voting to close with your new question.

Comment: @Botje I created the new question after examining the issue. You can close this question.